# How can I improve my question about developing a jQuery (polyfill) plugin?

Tags: support, specific-question

I've written this question in stackoverflow:
[How to make certain elements unobtainable with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218766/how-to-make-certain-elements-unobtainable-with-jquery)

If I got a downvote. I hope to believe it is because I failed to convey what I'm after with the question.
I asked why I got the `-1` in the comments but I didn't get a response.
English is not my main language so I hope I can learn more on how to get it right with your help.

I really want to make it a good question but I don't know what information is superfluous and what isn't.

Comment: My two cents: *Try something.* You're asking for a way to modify the behavior of all jQuery methods, which is quite broad, so posting your attempts at solving the problem is a must here. Also, on the XY problem department, it looks like you're after something akin to [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Good point! It is somewhat akin to the Shadow DOM. I may get some clues from polyfills to it. I still didn't do any actual attempts, though. Every time I try to mentally design a way of solving it, I find a failure to it.